# Custom Taglib in liferay using Spring MVC & Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, liferay, liferay-6

How do i proceed with creating a custom `Taglib` in a `liferay`.For now i have a `portlet` created in place. My obvious questions are:

1. Do i need to create a `hook plugin` and override a `jsp` for acheiving this target?
2. Do i need to download any `jars`?
3. Which all files would require changes?

I didnt find sufficient source for achieving this. Any guidance much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the taglib for? What has it to do with the portlet? A taglib in Liferay is not different from other JSP taglibs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a custom taglib in your own portlet just like you'd use it in any other web application: Include the TLD and the jar with the taglib's implementation, then include it in the JSPs that you're using in your portlets.

If you *want* to override Liferay's JSPs with your own JSP implementations (in a hook), you're typically limited to Liferay's own JSPs: A hook can't introduce a new Taglibrary to Liferay. However, if absolutely necessary you can add a custom taglib to Liferay with an ext plugin and use it from a hook.

But note that this has nothing to do with what's available to a portlet plugin: Portlet plugins are completely self-contained and can introduce whatever taglib they want with no need to customize Liferay itself.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for making it work..I was thinking there was some rocket science involved if we have to define custom taglibs in liferay..But no its the same approach that we use for normal jsps...Nicely mentioned..

Comment: Is this still the same with Liferay 7.0? With previous versions portlets were more less standard Java WebApps. Now they are OSGi modules - how and the "usual" way of including TLDs doesn't seem to work any longer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This indeed changed with Liferay 7. To introduce external dependencies, the easiest starting point that I'm aware of is https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/adding-dependencies-to-jsp-fragment-bundles

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that does not seem to cover custom Taglibs (that have .tld files) only JSP fragments. Would I need to annotate my Taglib classes with `@Component` then?